# Continue Ruby comment on Enter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

When writing a comment in Visual Studio code for Ruby code (e.g. simple text after `#`), hitting the `Enter` key does not automatically continue comment on next line.

Example:

```
# This is a comment I am writing. Now I hit 'Enter'.
I end up on this line without automatic `#` sign added.
```

Is there a standard way to have the comment continue automatically ? As in Typescript mode when using [TSDoc format](https://github.com/Microsoft/tsdoc).

**Note**: I already use [Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby), [Rubocop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misogi.ruby-rubocop), [Solargraph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.solargraph), [Yard documenter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pavlitsky.yard), [Better comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) and [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) extensions. Rewrap is the closest since it moves to next line automatically. But still not the best for several paragraphs comments.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using rubymine and this continuation of comments gets in my way more often than I actually need it. Which is to say "rubymine does this really well"

Comment: I didn't find how to disable it in RubyMine :) But someone on the contrary wants it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiline comments in Ruby.

You can do them between `=begin` and `=end`.

Note: `=begin` and `=end` should come in the beginning of line. They don't work inside of text.

But according to the codestyle, the use of such comments [is not recommended](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-block-comments).

Comment: Yes, this is more of "how do I make VSCode do this?"

Comment: Yes, the question about some plugin for VSC. But `=begin`/`=end` is universal way.

Comment: Yes, =begin/=end can make multiline comments, but not only I never used it, I haven't _seen_ one. It's just not used.

Comment: Most likely because editors today (well, some of them at least) are really good at commenting selected blocks of code with single-line comments.

Comment: In general, I think the problem is artificial. @Mic asked about a special format for comments. It seems to me that my answer can help him.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. Didn't see that yet in existing codebase, interesting! Doesn't quite solve my small issue though :)